# MySQL schedular every day in a time periode every hour

Tags: mysql, scheduled-tasks, event

This schedular i made doesn't work how i would like it to work.

The idea is that it will run every day in a time periode from 06:15:00 till 23:59:59 and in that only periode run every hour

That means it will run on 06:15 - 07:15 - 08:15 etc.. till 23:15 and start over again the next day

Server version: innodb_version:5.7.25

```
DELIMITER |

/*  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  */ 
ALTER 
    EVENT `Database`.`Import_data01_view` 
    ON SCHEDULE 
        EVERY 1 HOUR 
        STARTS '2019-04-15 06:15:00'  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO BEGIN

/* do things */


END |


DELIMITER ;
```

With the info i found my own solution for it:

```
DELIMITER |

/*  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  */ 
ALTER 
    EVENT `Database`.`Import_data01_view` 
    ON SCHEDULE 
        EVERY 1 HOUR
        STARTS str_to_date( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d 0615'), '%Y%m%d %H%i' )
        ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO BEGIN


 IF time(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) between time('06:14:59') and time('23:59:59')
      THEN

/* doe something */



end if;







END |


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: have you tried without the starts clause? (i'm asking because to me here is still around 12am)

Comment: Also, the documentation specify starts and ends clause. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html since you want it to run just for that day you should have the ends clause

Comment: Then i get a error : Errocode: 1525 Incorrect STARTS value: '06:15:00'

Comment: I don't want it run only for that day.. it need to run it everyday

Comment: Specify MySQL version. Simplify your event till simple stored procedure call. *it will run every day in a time periode from 06:15:00 till 23:59:59* No, it will run 24 times per day (at each XX:15:00) except first day.

Comment: innodb_version:5.7.25   owke and what do i need to make it so it will work? .. will run xx:15 start it from 06:00:00 and every hour till 00:00:00  so it runs on 6:15 - 7:15-8:15 etc.. till 23:15 and then the next day the same thing over..

Comment: *till 23:15 and then the next day* No. It's not cron. *Then i get a error : Errocode: 1525 Incorrect STARTS value: '06:15:00'* Now I'd like to ask - does the query which produces this error message had contained full datetime literal? or time part only?

Comment: @Akina can you give me a sample how it should work. how i have it in mind.. i add only the time part

Comment: *i add only the time part* That is wrong, `STARTS` clause needs full timestamp value. If you need *will run xx:15 start it from 06:00:00 and every hour till 00:00:00 so it runs on 6:15 - 7:15-8:15 etc.. till 23:15 and then the next day the same thing over..*, you must create 18 different daily schedules. Or (the best) one hourly schedule which checks current time on the start and performs action only when it is over 6:00.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- main action to perform at 6:15 - 7:15 - ... 23:15
CREATE PROCEDURE main_action()
BEGIN
    -- ...
END;

-- event procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE evt_action()
BEGIN
IF HOUR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) > 5 THEN 
    CALL main_action();
END IF;
END;

-- event
CREATE EVENT evt_name
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS '2019-04-15 06:15:00'
DO CALL evt_action();

-- start scheduler
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```